# Cassandra 2.0.7 to 2.1.2 sstable upgradesstables, compaction problems

Tags: database, cassandra, cassandra-2.0

We upgraded Cassandra (5+5 nodes) 2.0.9 to 2.1.2 (binaries) and ran nodetool upgradesstables one-by-one (bash script), after this we observe some problems:

1. on every node we observe about 50 "Pending Tasks" on one of them more than 500, it has persist for 5 days - when we started nodetool upgradesstables, even if concurrent_compactors is set to 8 cassandra never run more than 3-4 at the same time. One node with more than 500 tasks pending has about 11k files in column family directory...
   we have 2 ssd disks but during compacting there is up to 10MB/s reads and maximum 5MB/s writes - even if compaction_throughput_mb_per_sec is set to 32 or 64 or 256
2. during upgradesstables on some tables got :

```
WARN  [RMI TCP Connection(100)-10.64.72.34] 2014-12-21 23:53:18,953 ColumnFamilyStore.java:2492 - Unable to cancel in-progress compactions for reco_active_items_v1.  Perhaps there is an unusually large row in progress somewhere, or the system is simply overloaded.
INFO  [RMI TCP Connection(100)-10.64.72.34] 2014-12-21 23:53:18,953 CompactionManager.java:247 - Aborting operation on reco_prod.reco_active_items_v1 after failing to interrupt other compaction operations
```

`nodetool` is failing with:

```
Aborted upgrading sstables for atleast one column family in keyspace reco_prod, check server logs for more information.
```

3. on some nodes nodetool upgradesstables finished succefully but still can see *jb* files in column family directory.
4. `nodetool upgradesstables` on some nodes returns:

```
error: null
-- StackTrace --
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableReader.cloneWithNewStart(SSTableReader.java:952)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableRewriter.moveStarts(SSTableRewriter.java:250)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableRewriter.switchWriter(SSTableRewriter.java:300)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableRewriter.abort(SSTableRewriter.java:186)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.CompactionTask.runWith(CompactionTask.java:204)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.DiskAwareRunnable.runMayThrow(DiskAwareRunnable.java:48)
        at org.apache.cassandra.utils.WrappedRunnable.run(WrappedRunnable.java:28)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.CompactionTask.executeInternal(CompactionTask.java:75)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.AbstractCompactionTask.execute(AbstractCompactionTask.java:59)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.CompactionManager$4.execute(CompactionManager.java:340)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.CompactionManager$2.call(CompactionManager.java:267)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

This is our production env (24h) and we observe higher load on nodes , higher read latency even more than 1 sec.

Any advise...?

Comment: Did you find anything?

Comment: Have you got the solution?